# What causes an Operating System to become Corrupted?

Tags: boot

What Causes an Operating Systems ISO image to become Corrupted? I found an ISO image of windows 7 off the internet and now when I use windows 7, its extremely slow. What causes this? I cannot boot up the computer anymore from a CD disk. I want to remove the windows 7 from the computer and replace it with a clean copy of Windows 7.

Comment: Question appears to be off topic. The only bit relevant to Security is that this is most likely a pirate copy.

Comment: Its hard for me to explain what I'm trying to ask. sorry.

Answer (score 3):

*Corruption* is an act of Evil perpetrated by Bad People.

You discovered that when you download things "off the Internet", you sometimes don't obtain the genuine thing. If you need medication, do you go to the pharmacy, or will you prefer something sold by a shifty-looking guy in a back alley ? Don't you believe that inoculating yourself with substance of dubious provenance *might* imply inconvenient side-effects ?

Well, same here, except that you fed the bad pills to your computer, not to your own body. Fortunately, computers are not people: they can be reformatted(*) in order to restore their pristine, clean condition. That's the only remedy in your case.

<sup>(*) This works on humans, too, but is now frowned upon. Don't brainwash people at home, kids !</sup>

Comment: Thank You soo much! You helped alot! but how can I get it to boot up so i can replace it?

Comment: @Morgan That would be in your computer's BIOS settings. Turn on the computer or hard-reset it with the reset button (use the power button on its power supply, unplug the cord or remove the battery if nothing else works), and enter your BIOS by the designated key (or key combination) that's usually displayed on the screen on boot-up (or refer to your computer's manual). You'll be searching in its menu for a boot configuration page where you can set the order in which the computer searches your storage devices for a bootable image. Set your CD/DVD drive as the first item, save and reboot.